# Why can't I use NumPy functions in Canopy's IPython?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, enthought, canopy

I am struggling to use basic NumPy functions in my Python programme on Enthought's IPython, such as 'pi' and 'logspace'

It also says that the term 'plot' is undefined - has it changed?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had you imported numpy and matplotlib? If I had to guess, you used to start ipython with the `--pylab` flag. That flag is the destroyer of minds and hearts, and was recently deprecated.

A more merciful approach would be explicit imports that maintain namespaces, i.e.,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
```

However, if you want the mayhem to continue, you can execute `from pylab import *` at the top of your notebook.

Comment: forgive me, I am a beginner programmer but I'm slowly getting the hang of things - thanks for your help!